# can we use proxy pass according to server name in nginx with similar strings?

Tags: linux, nginx, webserver, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want to keep one server block, and I've created similar strings of server name, assume I've created server names like test-abc-proxy.example.com, test-def-proxy.example.com....and so on.
the server name consist -proxy in the string, but the proxy pass will be exactly same as the server name but -proxy will not be there, e.g

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name test-(can be anything)-proxy.example.com;
   location / {
   proxy_pass test-(can be anything).example.com
}
}
```

the issue is, proxy pass is not able take the url mapping from server_name, please suggest any solution.

Comment: Show exactly the configuration you are trying. If you want to use variables in the `proxy_pass` argument for defining the upstream hostname, you should use a [`resolver`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive.

Comment: I just want to use the server_name in proxy_pass, but removed -proxy in the dns used for proxy_pass, please note that server_name has regex in it, the problem is server_name has regex, I'm unable to use it in proxy_pass

Comment: Use a regex pattern with the named capture group: `server_name ~^(?<prefix>[^.]+)-proxy\.example\.com$;`, then use the `$prefix` variable with the `proxy_pass` directive: `proxy_pass http://$prefix.example.com;`. You need to specify a scheme (`http` or `https`) for the `proxy_pass` directive, it won't work without it.